# usage of "in which"

Tags: grammar

I have 2 different databases and I want to ask which is the most appropriate place to use in order to update data.

Could I say

- The information in which database will be updated?
- Which database will be used to update the information?
- From which database, the information will be used?

Comment: Only your second example is correct.

Comment: @RonaldSole: Not so. The first example is syntactically valid - it's just that *idiomatically*, we'd be more likely to resequence to *In which database will the information be updated?*